# Python and Vend JSON Queries

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Just trying to make some sense of the JSON outputs I'm getting from the Vend JSON API:

```
Item pagination
Item {u'pages': 10, u'results': 487, u'page_size': 50, u'page': 1}
Item customers
Item [{u'custom_field_3': u'', u'customer_code': u'WALKIN', u'custom_field_1': u'', u'balance': u'0', u'customer_group_id': u'xxx', u'custom_field_2': u'',
```

Is an example.

I'm trying to isolate a number of fields, such as 'customer_code' from the JSON output, but haven't seem to have worked it out quite yet.

My code:

```
response = requests.get('http://xxx.vendhq.com/api/customers',
                     auth=('xxx', 'yyy'))

data = response.json()

for item in data.items():
    print 'Item', item[0]
    print 'Item', item[1]
```

If I could "walk" across the JSON output, isolating the fields that would be pertinent, that would be really good code.

Comment: You'd better to include output of `print(data)`. Output of your program make it hard to understand the structure of the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the output and the given code, the structure of the data is:

```
{
    'pagination': {u'pages': 10, u'results': 487, u'page_size': 50, u'page': 1}
    'customers': [{u'custom_field_3': u'', u'customer_code': u'WALKIN',
                   u'custom_field_1': u'', u'balance': u'0',
                   u'customer_group_id': u'xxx', u'custom_field_2': u'', ..]
}
```

---

To get the customer_code list, you need to access a dict entry with the key `customers` and iterate it:

```
customer_codes = [customer['customer_code'] for customer in data['customers']]
```